# SQL: Earliest Date After Latest Null If Exists

Tags: sql, date

Using T-Sql I am looking to return the min date after the latest null if one exists and simply the min date on any products where there are no nulls. 
Table:

```
DateSold        Product
12/31/2012      A
1/31/2013   
2/28/2013       A
3/31/2013       A
4/30/2013       A
5/31/2013   
6/30/2013       A
7/31/2013       A
8/31/2013       A
9/30/2013       A
12/31/2012      B
1/31/2013       B
2/28/2013       B
3/31/2013       B
4/30/2013       B
5/31/2013       B
6/30/2013       B
7/31/2013       B
8/31/2013       B
9/30/2013       B
```

For product “A” `6/30/2013` is the desired return while for product “B” `12/31/2012` is desired. 
Result:

```
MinDateSold  Product
6/30/2013       A
12/31/2012      B
```

Any solutions will greatly be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: define "last". there is no order in sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does it for me, if there's a GROUP involved, otherwise how do you know whether the NULLs are in the run of A or B products? I realise this may not be exactly what you're after, but I hope it helps anyway.

```
WITH DATA_IN AS (
SELECT 1 as grp,
       convert(DateTime,'12/31/2012') as d_Date,
      'A' AS d_ch
  UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '1/31/2013',   NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '2/28/2013',    'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '3/31/2013',    'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '4/30/2013',    'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '5/31/2013',   NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '6/30/2013',    'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '7/31/2013',    'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '8/31/2013',    'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '9/30/2013',    'A' UNION ALL

SELECT 2, '12/31/2012',   'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '1/31/2013',    'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2/28/2013',    'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '3/31/2013',    'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '4/30/2013',    'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '5/31/2013',    'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '6/30/2013',    'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '7/31/2013',    'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '8/31/2013',    'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '9/30/2013',    'B'
)
SELECT
  grp as YourGroup,
  (SELECT Min(d_date) -- first date after...
   FROM DATA_IN
   WHERE d_date>
    Coalesce( -- either the latest NULL
     (SELECT max(d_Date)
      FROM DATA_IN d2
      WHERE d2.grp=d1.grp AND d2.d_ch IS NULL
     )
     , '1/1/1901'  -- or a base date if no NULLs
    )
  ) as MinDateSold
FROM DATA_IN d1
GROUP BY grp
```

Results :

```
1   2013-06-30 00:00:00.000
2   2012-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: This collected the correct dates but I am not sure if this is practical as my actual table will have ~ 500k records with ~ 100k products. Thank you though for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this is to count the number of `NULL` values that appear before a given row for a given value.  This divides the ranges into groups.  For each group, take the minimum date.  And, find the largest minimum date for each product:

```
select product, minDate
from (select product, NumNulls, min(DateSold) as minDate,
             row_number() over (partition by product order by min(DateSold) desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   (select count(*)
                    from table t2
                    where t2.product is null and t2.DateSold <= t.DateSold
                   ) as NumNulls
            from table t
           ) t
      group by Product, NumNUlls
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

In your data, there is no mixing of different products in a range, so this query sort of assumes that is true as well.